# Best Way to speed up a LOAD CSV in Neo4j

Tags: performance, csv, neo4j

I'm building up a Neo4j Database, in which I'll create k-ary trees with millions of nodes.
I'm currently using this setup:

1. Generate a .csv for the Vertices from php;
2. Generate a .csv for the Edges from php;
3. Run the following query for the Vertices in Neo4j:

   Using periodic commit 50000 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Nodi.csv' AS line 
   Create( :Vertex {name:line.name, 
   attr1: toFloat(line.attr1), attr2: toFloat(line.attr2), attr3: toFloat(line.attr3), attr4: toFloat(line.attr4), attr5: toFloat(line.attr5)})
4. Create Index on :Vertex(name)
5. Run the following query for the Edges in Neo4j:

   Using periodic commit 50000 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Archi.csv' AS line 
   Match (v_from:Vertex { name:line.from })
   Match (v_to:Vertex { name:line.to })

   Create( (v_from)<-[:EDGE {attr1: toFloat(line.attr1), attr2: toFloat(line.attr2), attr3: toFloat(line.attr3), attr4: toFloat(line.attr4), attr5: toFloat(line.attr5)}]-(v_to))

And then the Tree is created. This takes more or less 250 seconds in order to create a 2097151 nodes tree.

How can I improve this? ... I mean, maybe changing "Page cache sizing" or the "Heap sizing"... Is there something that I could do in a smarter way? Or something else that can improve this time...

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Do you ensure that the index is online before running the second `LOAD CSV` statement?

Comment: Yes, There is Server/Client System in which Clients send query 3. and 5. (In the list above) and between these two, in order to prevent Deadlocks and to be sure the Index is online, the Client send in a Sycronous way a request to the server in order to create the Index and wait for a response on the success.

Comment: The transaction to create an index will return immediately, and the index will be built in the background. To ensure the index is online you can use the `db.awaitIndex` procedure. For example: `CALL db.awaitIndex(":Person(name)"))`.

Comment: Does not seem to improve it at all :( 
It takes 300 seconds in this way creating a 2097151 nodes tree.